# What is the best practice for GET resources by multiple condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Using Express.js and MongoDB i want to get all teacher list when there is no query parameter with request url , I'm doing like below by a condition like when query is found then do this otherwise do that, is it efficient ? or any good suggestion . Thanks in Advance

```
export const getTeachers = (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.query.course_id) {
        try {
            Teacher.find({'course_ids':req.query.course_id}).exec()
                .then((teachers) => {
                    if (!teachers) {
                        return next(errorPlaceHolder(403, false, 'no teacher found'));
                    }
                    return res.status(200).json({
                        success: true,
                        message: 'Read course teacher',
                        teachers: teachers
                    })
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    next(error);
                });
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Error in get Teachers',
                error: e
            });
        }
    }else{
        try {
            Teacher.find().exec()
                .then((teachers) => {
                    if (!teachers) {
                        return next(errorPlaceHolder(403, false, 'no teacher found'));
                    }
                    return res.status(200).json({
                        success: true,
                        message: 'Read all teacher',
                        teachers: teachers
                    })
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    next(error);
                });
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Error in get Teachers',
                error: e
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can optimise the code like this

```
var findCriteria = {}
if(req.query.course_id) {
   findCriteria['course_ids'] = req.query.course_id;
}

Teacher.find(findCriteria).exec()
                    .then((teachers) => {

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use $where query. some manipulation might be needed to something like

```
Teacher.find({$where: function() { if(req.query.course_id && req.query.course_id != this.course_id){return false};return true; }}).exec()
                    .then((teachers) => { 
}
```

More on [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

Also note that $where doesn't uses indexes so it's bit costly.

Comment: You are welcome @OsmanGoniNahid. Please mark it as correct if it solved your problem.